# Spider plant thick stems

Tags: houseplants

My spider plant is growing 3 thick stems. I cut 3 off already because friend said they zap life from plant. Do I keep them? Will they produce babies?

---

[image][image]I am trying to figure how to add a photo and not sure this will work. This is a picture of the end of a stalky stem that is growing up, out of the spider. A couple weeks ago a friend said cut it so i cut 3 then 3 more have grown.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link underneath your post if you want to update it with new information. Thanks and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean the common green or green-and-white-leaved houseplant, then there's no reason to cut the stems off the plant unless you don't want little plants hanging down several feet from the mother plant. Leaving the stems on won't harm the plant in any way. Here's a plant that is horribly root bound (and will be until I repot it in March or April). It's in its winter quarters in my basement

[image: Spider Plant with offsets]

As you can see, it has more than a few babies.It's also blooming.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the excellent photos! They show the offsets forming from the mother plant, before they start drooping. In fact, the first photo actually shows the flower buds while the second seems to show a stem that's beginning to branch. Don't cut these and your plant will flower along the stems, with the plantlets forming a little later. Because your plant is trying to flower, I recommend leaving these stems because cutting them will actually weaken the plant—it will keep growing offsets to replace the ones you cut off. If you don't want the plantlets, then cut the stems after the flowers fade.

Comment: Thank you. These things aren't like the usual stem that grows babies. It's extremely thick and the end looks like wheat. It may be normal but I have never seen them this thick.

Comment: That is a beautiful spider !!!

Comment: Thanks - she's about 8 years old. Can you post a closeup of the think stem? I'm wondering if it's a root. I'll also try to post a closeup from my spider if I can find a root.

Comment: I cannot figure how to add a photo, I will keep trying to figure it out

Comment: I am trying to figure how to add a photo and not sure this will work. This is a picture of the end of a stalky stem that is growing up, out of the spider. A couple weeks ago a friend said cut it so i cut 3 then 3 more have grown.

Comment: Jurp i hope you can see this